# Android fragment widgets are null when returning from another activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager, fragment, lifecycle

**UPDATE**
I figured it has something to do with screen orientation. Indeed, when I play the differents actions without changing the orientation of the device, it doesn't cause any problems, the widgets are correctly valuated. As soon as I change the orientation, all the widgets become null when returning on the original activity.

**Original POST**

I'm having trouble with the lifecycle of Fragments or of a FragmentPagerAdapter, I don't quite know what is causing my problem.

Be aware that I'm new to Fragments, I must have misunderstood or forgotten something, but I haven't been able to find any answer on the existing posts. Also, note that I'm using the compatibility package as well as both libraries ActionBarSherlock and ViewPageIndicator.

Anyway, here is my situation :
 - I have a SherlockFragmentActivity A whose goal is to display a ViewPager containing two fragments, both fragments inherit SherlockFragment. So far, everything works fine, the views associated to both fragments are correct, I can do whatever I want with the widgets.
 - In the ActionBar, the user can click on an item that brings up a SherlockActivity B so he can either input and validate some data or cancel the input. The activity B is started with startActivityForResult() because I'm expecting a result in the activity A.

The idea is to refresh the content of both fragments in the ViewPager in onActivityResult() of activity A, if the user inputs and validates the form shown by activity B.

But then, when I try to update the views of the fragments in onActivityResult() if the user has validated the form, all the widgets in both fragments are now null. They were not null when the Fragments were first presented, but now they are and I haven't figured out any way to get their initial values. I've tried to play with the activities lifecycle, without success.

Here are the most important bits of my code :

**The adapter**

```
public class TabGameSetPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private final List<Fragment> fragments;

public TabGameSetPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    this.fragments = fragments;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {
    return this.fragments.get(position);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return this.fragments.size();
}

@Override
public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
    switch(position) {
        case 0:
            return App.getApplication().getString(R.string.lblGamesTitle);
        case 1:
            return App.getApplication().getString(R.string.lblSynthesisTitle);
        default:
            return "Unknown[" + position + "]";
    }
}
```

**The activity with the pager**

```
public class TabGameSetActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements IRefreshableGameSetContainer {

private ViewPager mPager;

private PagerAdapter mPagerAdapter;

private GameSetGamesFragment gameSetGamesFragment = GameSetGamesFragment.newInstance();

private GameSetSynthesisFragment gameSetSynthesisFragment = GameSetSynthesisFragment.newInstance();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    try {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.simple_titles);

        // initialize the pager
        this.initialisePaging();

    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        AuditHelper.handleActivityException(this, e);
    }
}

private void initialisePaging() {
    this.gameSetGamesFragment = GameSetGamesFragment.newInstance();
    this.gameSetSynthesisFragment = GameSetSynthesisFragment.newInstance();

    List<Fragment> fragments = newArrayList();
    fragments.add(this.gameSetGamesFragment);
    fragments.add(this.gameSetSynthesisFragment);

    this.mPagerAdapter = new TabGameSetPagerAdapter(super.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);
    this.mPager = (ViewPager) super.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    this.mPager.setAdapter(this.mPagerAdapter);
    this.mPager.setCurrentItem(this.startPage-1);

    TitlePageIndicator indicator = (TitlePageIndicator)findViewById(R.id.indicator);
    indicator.setViewPager(mPager);
    indicator.setFooterIndicatorStyle(IndicatorStyle.Triangle);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    try {
        if (requestCode == RequestCodes.ADD_GAME) {
            if (resultCode == ResultCodes.AddGame_Ok) {
                this.refresh();
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}


@Override
public void refresh() {
    this.gameSetGamesFragment.refresh();
    this.gameSetSynthesisFragment.refresh();
}
```

}

See especially the onActivityResult() which handles a call to the refresh() method on both fragments.

**One of the fragments**

```
public class GameSetGamesFragment extends SherlockFragment implements IRefreshableGameSetContainer {

private View mViewTabGameSet;

private LinearLayout playersLayout;

private LinearLayout gamesLayout;

private ScoresRow playerScoresRow;

private PlayersRow playersRow;  

public static GameSetGamesFragment newInstance() {
    return new GameSetGamesFragment();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    this.mViewTabGameSet = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablegameset, null);

    this.playersLayout = (LinearLayout)this.mViewTabGameSet.findViewById(R.id.playersLayout);
    this.gamesLayout = (LinearLayout)this.mViewTabGameSet.findViewById(R.id.gamesLayout);

    this.playerScoresRow = new ScoresRow(this.getActivity(), App.getBizService().getPlayers());
    this.playersRow = new PlayersRow(this.getActivity(), App.getBizService().getPlayers());

    this.playersLayout.addView(this.playersRow);
    this.playersLayout.addView(this.playerScoresRow);

    this.progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(this.getActivity());

    this.refreshGameRows();

    return this.mViewTabGameSet;
}

protected void refreshGameRows() {
    this.gamesLayout.removeAllViews();

    for (View rowToDisplay : rowsToDisplay) {
        this.gamesLayout.addView(rowToDisplay);
    }

    ...
}

@Override
public void refresh() {
    this.refreshGameRows();
}
```

}

I didn't put all my code here, but the most important bits are present. As you can see, the fragment's onCreateView() method calls refreshGameRows(), so does the fragment's refresh() method. So both methods do basically the same stuff in terms of UI rendering.

However, when the method refresh() is called in onActivityResult() of the TabGameSetActivity class, all the fragments widgets are null: gamesLayout, mViewTabGameSet... Which I don't understand since onCreateView() was previously called and valuated properly all the objects.

Right now, an exception is thrown and the ui is hence not updated. I need to change the orientation of my device so that the first activity be recreated and all its child fragments as well. But there's no way I can ship this to my end users :/

So any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.